# Cannot deploy war file on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, war, mybatis

I tried to deploy my war file into tomcat. I tried to deploy via IDE IDEA and via manager on tomcat, but it doesn't work. In log I could see theese rows and no errors :( coul you please help what is wrong?

catalina.out

```
/home/user/OPT/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/user/.IntelliJIdea14/system/tomcat/Unnamed_webapp
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/user/OPT/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/user/OPT/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/user/OPT/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/user/OPT/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
[2015-05-13 08:28:48,166] Artifact core:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
V 13, 2015 8:28:49 DOP. org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/IDEA/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
V 13, 2015 8:28:50 DOP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
V 13, 2015 8:28:50 DOP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
V 13, 2015 8:28:50 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1654 ms
V 13, 2015 8:28:50 DOP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
V 13, 2015 8:28:50 DOP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
V 13, 2015 8:28:50 DOP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
V 13, 2015 8:28:50 DOP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
V 13, 2015 8:28:50 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 131 ms
Connected to server
[2015-05-13 08:28:50,816] Artifact core:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
V 13, 2015 8:28:51 DOP. org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/user/WORKSPACE/whatACore/target/core/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
V 13, 2015 8:28:51 DOP. org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/user/WORKSPACE/whatACore/target/core/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.54.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
V 13, 2015 8:29:00 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/user/OPT/tomcat/webapps/manager
```

The proble is with MyBatis, when you make a mistake in select clause and use resultType instead of resultMap, you can build war file, but application will never start and no error is shown :/

Answer (score 0):

See the best way is to create the war file first and then deploy it in the Tomcat->webapps folder. Have you  managed to create the war file successfully?

Comment: Yes, my war file was creted succesfully, I tried to copy this war into webapps, after start tomcat it created core file in webapps, but I cannot acces to manager website, it still loading the website, but no error enywhere

Comment: was the project folder extracted succesfully? did you check if the content is intact?If evrything's proper you can directly open a browser and hit http://localhost:port/projectname to load the home page and  don't need to access the manager,

Comment: Yes, it was extracted succesfully, but you can't acces to the  localhost:port/projectname and almost you cannot reach manager website, tomcas looks blocked, but I found the problem, the problem was with MyBatis, when you make a mistake in select clause and use resultType instead of resultMap, you can build war file, but application will never start and no error is shown :/ Thanks a lot for your time!